# why return null Repository implementation for Entity Framework when test mock unit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mocking

hi iam use mock unit test with ef
when test build my test failed when debug test I am getting the below error.

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.'

[TestClass]
public class Role_Test2
{

```
private Mock<IUserService> _mockRepository;
private IUserService _service;
Mock<IUnitOfEntity> _mockUnitWork;
Mock<ISecurityAuthorizService> _ISecurityAuthorizService;
Mock<IMapper> _mapper;
List<User> listCountry;

[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
    _mockRepository = new Mock<IUserService>();
    _mockUnitWork = new Mock<IUnitOfEntity>();
    _mapper = new Mock<IMapper>() ;
    _ISecurityAuthorizService = new Mock<ISecurityAuthorizService>() ;

_service = new AdminCentral.NetCore.ServiceLayer.EFServices.UserService(_mockUnitWork.Object, _mapper.Object, _ISecurityAuthorizService.Object);
//    _service = new UserService(_mockUnitWork.Object, _mockRepository.Object);
    listCountry = new List<User>() {
   new User() { IdCode = 1, Name = "US" },
   new User() { IdCode = 2, Name = "India" },
   new User() { IdCode = 3, Name = "Russia" }
  };
}

[TestMethod]
public void Country_Get_All()
{
    //Arrange
    _mockRepository.Setup(x => x.count(10)).Returns(listCountry);

    //Act
    List<User> results = _service.count(10) as List<User>;

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(results);
    Assert.AreEqual(3, results.Count);
}
```

this my code layerservic
i sure return null IUnitOfEntity

```
  public class UserService : BaseService, IUserService
        {
            #region Fields
              private readonly IUnitOfEntity _iUnitOfEntity;
              private readonly DbSet<User> _users;
              private readonly IMapper _mapper;
              private readonly ISecurityAuthorizService _iSecurityAuthorizService;
            #endregion


            public UserService(IUnitOfEntity unitOfEntity, IMapper mapper,   ISecurityAuthorizService isecurityauthorizservice)
            {
                _iUnitOfEntity = unitOfEntity;
                _users = _iUnitOfEntity.Set<User>();
                _mapper = mapper;
                _iSecurityAuthorizService = isecurityauthorizservice;
            }
       public IList<User> count(int id)
            {
                   return _users.Where(x => x.UserId == id).ToList();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of the UserService `_iUnitOfEntity.Set<User>()` is called, however, this method was not mocked, and will either throw the exception or return null depending on the implementation.
You'll probably want to add a mock implementation which returns a list of users

```
//Arrange
_mockRepository.Setup(x => x.count(10)).Returns(listCountry);
_mockUnitWork.Setup(x => x.Set()).Returns(listUsers);
```